# Error starting apache, httpd: Configuration error: More than one MPM loaded

Tags: apache

I get the following when I try to start the apache server,
I built the 2.4.6 version and have placed in a local location.

```
[apacheas@twproxy1 bin]$ ./apachectl -k start
AH00534: httpd: Configuration error: More than one MPM loaded.
```

Based on some information provided on some sites, I tries to list down the modules available (not sure!) as below.

```
[apacheas@twproxy1 bin]$ ./httpd -l

Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  mod_so.c
  http_core.c
  event.c
```

What could be going wrong?

This is related to the recent Heart Bleed bug in openssl -- for which we were advised to upgrade both apache and openssl version.
We did all, but stuck with the above problem/

Comment: This was due to the line added in httpd.conf Load Module *mpm* -- I just commented this line and it all went perfect after that.

Answer (score 37):

Check all your enabled mods inside mods-enabled directory. If you already enabled `mpm_prefork`, you should disable the `worker` module.

```
sudo a2dismod worker

sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! Not sure why though, as I hadn't made any changes to server environment so really random that this error just started happening.

Comment: Any information on why this was the case? Fixed it for me.

Comment: FYI:  Running just "sudo a2dismod" wil show you conflicting mpm_module names.  In my case they were mpm_event and pmp_prefork.  I disabled mpm_event since I wanted to have mpm_prefork running.   The conflict resulted from installation of some php7.0 related things.

Comment: Unfortunately `a2dismod` seems to be specific to debian distros

Answer (score 15):

Look in: `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d`

You'll find a file called: `00-mpm.conf`

You can uncomment only one out of those 3 lines:

```
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
#LoadModule mpm_worker_module modules/mod_mpm_worker.so
#LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so
```

More informations here : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mpm.html

Comment: Old but true :)

Answer (score 7):

In Ubuntu solution is same as above but there is is only difference of file :

```
cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled

root@ip:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled# ll mpm_*

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Jun 30 10:33 mpm_event.conf -> ../mods-available/mpm_event.conf

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Jun 30 10:33 mpm_event.load -> ../mods-available/mpm_event.load

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Jun 30 11:36 mpm_prefork.conf -> ../mods-available/mpm_prefork.conf

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Jun 30 11:36 mpm_prefork.load -> ../mods-available/mpm_prefork.load

root@ip:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled# cat mpm_event.load

# Conflicts: mpm_worker mpm_prefork mpm_itk

#LoadModule mpm_event_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_event.so



root@ip-10-0-0-249:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled# cat mpm_prefork.load
# Conflicts: mpm_event mpm_worker mpm_itk

LoadModule mpm_prefork_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
```

**ie comment out any one of the above module**

```
root@ip:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled# service apache2 restart
```

This will do !! It worked for me !

Comment: I was using mod-php7 and found that I had to disable `mpm_event` and leave `mpm_prefork` in order for it to work

Comment: what should we comment actually

Comment: for me it worked not comment, but removing the symbolic links on mods-enabled. Is this correct ?

Answer (score 3):

To fix the "More than one MPM loaded" error under Centos 7.0 after updating Apache try the following:

```
sudo vim /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf
```

and comment this line

```
#Change from
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so

#To
#LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
```

The issue is that multiple [Multi-Processing Modules](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/prefork.html) are being loaded meaning Apache can't decide what model it should be using, causing this error.

Comment: I ran into this last night on a RedHat 7 machine. The same fix worked there as well, but wondering why it was loaded twice. The change came in via yum updates but haven't had a chance to look into it further. It's been working fine since Oct '18.