# Deploy OSPOS docker container on heroku display : Application error

Tags: docker, heroku, open-source, point-of-sale

for my point of sale I try to install ospos, on my computer I used the docker image and everything works fine, but when I deploy on Heroku following this steps :

```
Install the Heroku CLI
Download and install the Heroku CLI.

If you haven't already, log in to your Heroku account and follow the prompts to create a new SSH public key.

$ heroku login
Create a new Git repository
Initialize a git repository in a new or existing directory

$ cd my-project/
$ git init
$ heroku git:remote -a vente-a-domicile
Deploy your application
Commit your code to the repository and deploy it to Heroku using Git.

$ git add .
$ git commit -am "make it better"
$ git push heroku master
You can now change your main deploy branch from "master" to "main" for both manual and automatic deploys, please follow the instructions here.
Existing Git repository
For existing repositories, simply add the heroku remote

$ heroku git:remote -a vente-a-domicile
```

the page where my app is installed show the following message :

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
Heroku logs --tail
```

so I launch the command and get this result :

```
2022-10-29T21:24:40.812614+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user codescooper@gmail.com
2022-10-29T21:24:40.812614+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user codescooper@gmail.com
2022-10-29T21:24:40.957922+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user codescooper@gmail.com
2022-10-29T21:24:40.957922+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user codescooper@gmail.com
2022-10-29T21:31:58.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user codescooper@gmail.com
2022-10-29T21:32:07.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/42df0c38-6c04-4972-97d2-93821d2e9b63/activity/builds/2cb20d81-bfc3-4a9d-8808-b14f1db678ed
2022-10-29T21:38:09.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user codescooper@gmail.com
2022-10-29T21:38:17.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build output: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/42df0c38-6c04-4972-97d2-93821d2e9b63/activity/builds/85f13e98-e3e3-4de7-9ede-29519171e35a
2022-10-31T21:48:41.178521+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user codescooper@gmail.com
2022-10-31T21:48:41.178521+00:00 app[api]: Deployed web (1ca1d62ad467) by user codescooper@gmail.com
2022-10-31T21:48:41.195334+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user codescooper@gmail.com
2022-10-31T21:48:50.095189+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `apache2-foreground`
2022-10-31T21:48:51.083067+00:00 app[web.1]: AH00534: apache2: Configuration error: More than one MPM loaded.
2022-10-31T21:48:51.216874+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-10-31T21:48:51.270570+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-10-31T21:48:51.276875+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-10-31T21:48:59.652673+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `apache2-foreground`
2022-10-31T21:49:00.634576+00:00 app[web.1]: AH00534: apache2: Configuration error: More than one MPM loaded.
2022-10-31T21:49:00.773706+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-10-31T21:49:00.828894+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-10-31T21:49:01.418603+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=vente-a-domicile.herokuapp.com request_id=ea225fc8-bfd5-4956-ace7-65d90de1cf51 fwd="160.154.248.41" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-10-31T21:49:02.940239+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=vente-a-domicile.herokuapp.com request_id=2833440f-ccd9-4b0a-84f9-a3ef177f013d fwd="160.154.248.41" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Can you please explain how to solve it and make my app available?
thank u

Comment: "but when I deploy on Heroku"—how are you doing this? Also using Docker? [Are you using the container registry or the `heroku.yml` path?](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deploying-with-docker) Also, "apache2: Configuration error: More than one MPM loaded"—[did you modify your Apache configuration somehow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24060620/354577)?

Comment: just follow the steps described on heroku dashboard, i will add on my post. i used the container registry, i dn't remember change something about apache2. i have to do it to slove the problem ?

Comment: The instructions you quote above don't show a container registry deploy. Unless you added a step where you set your app's stack to `container`, you did a non-docker deploy. And doing that _should_ have auto-detected your application as a Node.js project, yet it appears to be using the PHP buildpack... are you entirely sure you didn't do anything different when you deployed?

Comment: that was some days ago, so i think i will do it again taking care of all the steps that you explain. if you have another advice i'm taker